# Clojure: vars, atoms, and refs (oh my)

Tags: clojure

also: defs, java fields, agents

The clojure website has documentation for these concepts:

- [Vars](http://clojure.org/vars)
- [Atoms](http://clojure.org/atoms)
- [Refs](http://clojure.org/refs)
- [Agents](http://clojure.org/agents)

I understand the words, but I don't conceptually get the *purpose / meaning* of these. When should I / how can I know when to use them?

Comment: related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/143341/is-re-defing-idiomatic-in-clojure/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Use **Refs** for synchronous, coordinated and shared changes.
- Use **Agents** for *asynchronous*, independent and shared changes.
- Use **Atoms** for synchronous, independent and shared changes.
- Use **Vars** for isolated changes.

*EDIT*
The links you posted are highly important to read, however I also recommends this: [Software Transactional Memory](http://java.ociweb.com/mark/stm/article.html)

Keep in mind that aborted transactions will be ***replayed***. What does this mean?
It means that the code inside **dosync** could be executed a couple of times, so you need to be careful the code should be side effects free.

One use of **agents** is to have a controlled side effects. Consider this:

```
(dosync
  (send log-agent message args)
  (alter reference function))
```

The STM will hold all of the actions needed to be sent to agents until succeed.

What is difference between **atoms** and **agents**?
Updates to agents will happen asynchronously at some point of the future, updates to atoms will happened immediately.

Atoms and agents don't need to run inside a transaction, refs should be (*coordinated* changes, remember?)

Comment: This is starting to make sense... When would I use an agent instead of an atom? And what does the coordinated part of Refs mean?

Comment: An agent is good for sending jobs to that you want to get done but don't care when they happen. You might not care exactly when a log gets written to, just as long as it does get written to eventually.